# Yii2 get controller/action from url

Tags: yii2

How in yii2 get controller/action from url.
Attention!!! I ask about Yii2. There are answers that consern only Yii1 at this forum.

Added.
I find smth like Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl('http://eewee.djn'));
but in yii2

Added.
I get refferer url to anather conrtoller, where i want to parse it url by yii2 and get controller/action.

Comment: What are you speakeing about?

Comment: @yeryr  please explain better what you need ... show a sample or the code where you need.. what you are looking for .

Comment: Maybe this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#parseUrl-detail

Comment: I wrote about yii2 not yii1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
<?php echo Yii::$app->controller->id; // controller id ?>


<?php echo Yii::$app->controller->action->id; // controller action id ?>
```

Comment: ? i don't want to get the CURRENT controller/action,  i want to get controller/action from the URL

Comment: This Is What Shahzad Answered @yeryr.

Comment: I have REFERER URL from the other controller- his answer is wrong- see my example- read my queastion attentively

Answer (score 4):

That worked for me

```
$request = new Request(['url' => parse_url(\Yii::$app->request->referrer, PHP_URL_PATH)]);
$url = \Yii::$app->urlManager->parseRequest($request);
list($controller, $actionID) = \Yii::$app->createController($url[0]);
```

You receive your action in `$actionID` and controller name in the `$controller->id`. The Request object needed because  such construction:

```
list($controller, $actionID) =
    \Yii::$app->createController(parse_url(\Yii::$app->request->referrer, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

not works with parameters in url.

Comment: any solution for parameters in URL?

Answer (score 1):

```
list($controller, $actionID) = Yii::$app->createController($url);
```

If you need action as Object try this

```
$action = $controller->createAction($actionID);
```